# Visualizar dados do banco de dados SQL de forma parecida com o banco de dados do Access

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, microsoft-access

Boa tarde senhores

Eu sou leigo no assunto referente a banco de dados SQL e estou tentando visualizar os dados de um banco de dados SQL em forma de tabela, segue abaixo o banco de dados de nome **E3** já criado sendo visualizado pelo software SQL Express, **é possivel visualizar os dados deste banco de dados em forma de tabela semelhante a como é feito pelo Microsoft Access?** Desde já agradeço a ajuda!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já sou familiarizado com banco de dados no Access, eu criei um banco de dados no SQL porém estou com dificuldade em analizar as tabelas do banco de dados, eu consigo fazer isto facilmente no Access

[image: Exemplo de visualização de dados pelo Access]

Comment: Se nenhuma das interfaces disponíveis para seu SGBD atendeu a suas necessidades você sempre pode conectar a seu banco de dados utilizando MS Access e um conector ODBC.

Comment: Vitor, você pode expandir o nó tabelas, clicar com o botão direito do mouse sobre uma tabela e depois experimentar as opções "Selecionar n linhas superiores"  e "Editar n linhas superiores"

Comment: Muito obrigado @imex , você conhece algum curso de SQL server ou um caminho que eu possa percorrer para entender um pouco mais sobre SQL server?

Comment: Desculpe, vou ficar devendo

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite

Eu consegui visualizar os dados em forma de tabela pressionando o botão direito do mouse no arquivo tabela e selecionando a opção Selecionar 1000 linhas superiores segue imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -3):

Para fazer isso depende do software (SGBD) que você escolher usar, um que tenha essa interface. Eu recomendo o EMS SQL Manager, tem uma versão para cada bando de dados.